# Emails from my domain (hmailserver) are always in YahooSpam

Tags: email, spam, dkim

Hi during sending out my mails from my domain luxpost.com they are placed directly into spam folder in yahoo. I tried to analyse the raw header and got only DKIM warnings. So I placed a DKIM entry in DNS like some tutorials on the net. But I still get `dkim=permerror (no key)`. Here the complete header:

```
Authentication-Results: mta4199.mail.ne1.yahoo.com;
 dkim=permerror (no key) header.i=@luxpost.com header.s=dkim;
 spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=@luxpost.com;
 dmarc=pass(p=quarantine sp=NULL dis=none) header.from=luxpost.com;
```

I'm using Hmailserver on windows server and PLESK DNS management (Windows DNS).

DNS entry:

```
key75._domainkey.luxpost.com.   TXT v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; p= [HERE IS MY KEY];
```

Comment: The formatting here is so erratic that it's hard to tell really what is what; but if the backslashes are genuine, they are probably wrong; and if you have a space after `p=` that could be a problem too.

Comment: Having SPF is of course no guarantee that your messages will be accepted or welcome; it just makes it possible to verify that the sender is not forged (though SPF is not entirely robust e.g. when forwarwding).

Answer (score 1):

Looking up this key in DNS reveals that you have erratic backslashes where they do not belong.

```
bash$ dig +short txt key75._domainkey.luxpost.com. | fold -w 64
"v=DKIM1\\; k=rsa\\; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCA
QEAkFwX7ioR8/PJjebZ4n/Rf9r7iOtKdARKt6cpxXkXefXLg70KXSVujz24UaUiq
hbzSKH7a6z36KIUM49xunXKrygag/ofcuS4h8eGEvaF7XId1DPxgr74+snuX9kXj
Qt3JnkUKB81LPvx43CLXJXTmvEyfZnAxtYF8/VF8wFNLhUGGxgsi5ntOcSjMfPGs
" "kaIADLbiKl1ZeGjm96BUGn9eag8IsPToQE8T5ohBxHUtsymRb0uTuXfhs1yJX
5xzt4rlXeSXLXuBjfk/JSv/1bLyHRQC0QZ+SzbidTjEhgeov0nDWjK0At48UdMIg
oYTwAVLkW/XXmMx99egMxg+3WlDwIDAQAB;"
```

The key appears to be [correctly split](http://hack.limbicmedia.ca/how-to-split-dns-dkim-records-properly/) but the semicolon at the end also looks spurious to me.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer , I removed the backslahes and the semicolon at the end, no change

Comment: DNS has caching, you need to wait for the TTL to expire before the changes are really live.

Comment: Or, change the selector to something else than `key75`

Answer (score 0):

In your Authentication-Results header it shows the receiving server found a selector named "dkim" (`header.s=dkim`), which is reported missing.
Yet you publish a selector named "key75", which also seems to be not existing in dns at the time of writing.